# jquery, how to run a function as soon as another function ends

Tags: jquery, function

*Note: Re-writing question:

I am trying to write the following **outside** of the individual function calls:

example:

```
function f1(){
    do something 1
}
function f2(){
    do something 2   
}

run function 1
when done
run function 2
```

**(See comments below for jsfiddles)**

Problem is, the boxes load at the same time. Behavior SHOULD be, load red, when done, load green.

If this isn't a common method in jQuery, let me know, maybe I'm just chasing a ghost...

Comment: This is what I want to happen: http://jsfiddle.net/kolbaba/Wjmfw/1/

These two are attempts at doing this: http://jsfiddle.net/kolbaba/7LvGS/3/, http://jsfiddle.net/kolbaba/SCKTV/8/

Comment: Depending on what 'do something' is doing, the answers will change. If your 'do something' does anything that is asynchronous, then you will need to do some of the tricks provided below. However, if they are all synchronous calls, then they will execute synchronously. In otherwords, if there is no async, they will run in order if you just call them one after the other.

Comment: @aaronfrost it is an asynch attempt. I have 10 levels in a game, each level is a function. I want to pull fn's 1-10 into a lean clean function, without all the nested functions and effects and animations... See here for a visualization of what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/kolbaba/c4LQv/1/

Comment: let me know if you need any more help. If function 1 does anything async, then your code will not run as you expect. If any of the functions have async calls, then you have no guarantee in what order they will finish. Using deferreds as I showed below, will allow you to have a contract about what order the functions will execute in. If your functions only perform sync tasks, then you will not need deferreds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply call the second function at the end of the first.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

  function firstFunction(){
    alert("this is the first function!");
    secondFunction();
  }
  function secondFunction(){
    alert("this is the second function!");
  }

  firstFunction();
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SCKTV/2/)

Alternatively, if you do not wish to call the second function every time you call the first, you could simply call them sequentially

```
firstFunction();
secondFunction();
```

This works because it will wait until `firstFunction` is done before it moves on to `secondFunction`
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SCKTV/3/)

Comment: Yes, but let me give you the use case. I have 10 point and click game levels created. and I've packaged them up in functions. (ie. function level1). I want to write a separate function at the top of the js file to pull each "level function" and "order" them how I see fit. This way it would be easier to swap levels around without having to hop into tons of code... does that make sense? run level1function, when done, run level2function, when done, run level3function and so on...

Comment: @nthChild as long as you don't have anything asynchronous, placing a call to the next function at the end of the current one will do the trick.

Comment: @nthChild you mentioned `point and click` which would imply the need for `click` event handlers. You would have to show your code and markup for any specifics but if each `level` has a series of things to click on then the last one could have a `.click(function(){nextlevel();});` to advance to the next level. If it is something based on clicking, then you will probably want it to be contained in click handlers and nothing directly sequential.

Answer (score 14):

Depends on the functions.

### Short answer:

For **synchronous** functions: Just call them one after the other.

For **asynchronous** functions: Depends on what makes it asynchronous.

jQuery animations? Define a callback parameter from the animation's method or from the fx queue's Promise object.

setTimeout/setInterval/something else? Most likely, the functions will need to be rewritten to provide a callback or Deferred/Promise object.

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zarjay/42PhM/) or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/zarjay/42PhM/2/) for examples.

### Long answer:

According to the jsFiddles in your comments, you've got these two functions:

```
function firstFunction(){
    $(".one").fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut();
}
function secondFunction(){
    $(".two").fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut();
}
```

You want `secondFunction` to run after `firstFunction`, and you'd prefer not to tamper with these functions. If that's the case, there's only one solution I can think of: Get a [Promise object](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) from the element that `firstFunction` is animating, and then define `secondFunction` as a success handler:

```
firstFunction();
$('.one').promise().then(secondFunction);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zarjay/42PhM/)

`promise()` returns a Promise object bound to the current animation state of that element. `$('.one').promise().then(secondFunction)` is essentially saying "I promise to run `secondFunction` when the current animation for `.one` is done.

If you're willing to tamper with the existing functions, you could also call `secondFunction` as a callback parameter of the `fadeOut` within `firstFunction`, but that's not a very elegant solution.

If you're willing to rewrite your functions, the ideal solution is to tame your async functions by using Deferreds and Promises. Here's a quick primer:

- In jQuery, a [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object is a special object you can use to define the success/fail state of a function. You use this inside your functions.
- A [Promise](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) object is a special object that you can use to add callbacks to those success/fail states. You use this outside your functions.

Using these tools, you can rewrite your functions to specify when they're "done," and you can give code outside your functions the ability to know when (and execute after) they're done.

Rewritten to use Deferred and Promise, the code looks like this:

```
function firstFunction(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $(".one").fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(function() {
        deferred.resolve();
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}
function secondFunction(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $(".two").fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut(function() {
        deferred.resolve();
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}

firstFunction().then(secondFunction);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zarjay/42PhM/1/)

If all your functions are written this way, you can control their execution order and have them run sequentially using [`then()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/). Here's a more thorough example:

```
function one(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $(".one").fadeOut(500, function() {
        $(this).appendTo('body').fadeIn(500, function() { deferred.resolve(); });
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}

function two(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $(".two").fadeOut(1500, function() {
        $(this).appendTo('body').fadeIn(500, function() { deferred.resolve(); });
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}

function three(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $(".three").fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $(this).appendTo('body').fadeIn(500, function() { deferred.resolve(); });
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}

function four(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $(".four").fadeOut(750, function() {
        $(this).appendTo('body').fadeIn(500, function() { deferred.resolve(); });
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}

function five(){
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    $(".five").fadeOut(600, function() {
        $(this).appendTo('body').fadeIn(500, function() { deferred.resolve(); });
    });
    return deferred.promise();
}

one()
    .then(two)
    .then(three)
    .then(four)
    .then(five);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zarjay/42PhM/2/)

Answer (score 6):

Deferreds are an option. You could always do the following:

```
$.when(firstFunction()).then(secondFunction);
```

The only trick is that inside firstFunction, you would need to do the following:

```
function firstFunction(){
    var deferred = $.Deffered();

    $.get(url,function(r){
        deferred.resolve();
    });

    return deferred;
}
```

The when function will wait until the deferred returned by the firstFunction call is resolved. Once the deferred is resolved (in the ajax success callback) the '.then' statement will fire, calling your secondFunction.

The jQuery docs explain the Deferred API very well.

Answer (score 4):

you can use the jquery Callbacks function, from v1.7up

```
var callbacks = $.Callbacks();
callbacks.add( firstFunction );
callbacks.add( secondFunction );
callbacks.fire( );
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if the functions are asynchronous. http://jsfiddle.net/7LvGS/4/

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
 firstFunction(function(){
        secondFunction();
    });
```

write

```
firstFunction();
secondFunction();
```

Comment: Hi George, I tried this, here: http://jsfiddle.net/kolbaba/SCKTV/5/... it seems to load the functions at the same time, rather than one, then the other... your thoughts?

Comment: I put the following code in the javascript section:
`$(document).ready(function() {
 var i = 'a';
    function firstFunction(){
        i = i+ '_first_func';
        $(".one").fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut();
    }
    function secondFunction(){
        i = i+ '_second_func';
        $(".two").fadeIn(1000).delay(2000).fadeOut();
    }
    
    firstFunction();
    secondFunction();
    alert(i);
});`

The result was

a_first_func_second_func

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently. If you have a bunch of functions that do async stuff, just make them all to return a Deferred, which you manually resolve when the function async job is finished. Then you can put the functions in an array and run them sequentially:

```
// Sample asynchronous function that returns Deferred
var f = function(name){
    console.log('Function root start', name);
    var d = $.Deferred();
    d.done(function(result){
        console.log('Async work finish', name, result);
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            d.resolve('Hello');
        }, 200);
    }, 1000);

    console.log('Function root finish', name);
    return d;
};

// Array with functions
var defs = [];
defs.push(f.bind(null, 1));
defs.push(f.bind(null, 2));
defs.push(f.bind(null, 3));

// Recursive sequential calling
var i = 0;
var runAtIndex = function (i) {
    i < defs.length && defs[i]().done(function() { runAtIndex(i + 1); });
}
runAtIndex(i);
```